# zend2: how to destroy exact session?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am new to Zend2. I dont know how to destroy the particular session.

```
$check_username = $session->offsetExists('sess_chk_usr_name');
if(empty($check_username))
{
   $session->offsetSet('sess_chk_usr_name', 'test user');
}
```

I need to remove the session sess_chk_usr_name, please help.

Comment: `$session->offsetSet('sess_chk_usr_name', null);`?

Comment: @Mike: Here you assign the value of session to null. I need to unset the sess_chk_usr_name.

Comment: That's not a session, it's a key in the session. Destroying the session would be [`session_destroy()`](http://php.net/session_destroy) which would blow away everything.

Comment: Look at the definition yourself https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Session/Storage/SessionArrayStorage.php#L133. There's offsetUnset(). Is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry for that, i need to unset the sess_chk_usr_name key only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I realise it's been answered, but it gets asked a lot. Session containers in ZF2 are essentially [ArrayObjects](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php), with the flag [ARRAY_AS_PROPS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php#arrayobject.constants.array-as-props) set. What that means is they behave like an array AND an object, so not only can you use the methods the object supplies to access properties, you can act on them just like an array (although it should be noted that the `array_*` family of functions don't work)

Setters

```
$session = new Container('foo');

// these are all equivalent means to the same end
$session['bar'] = 'foobar';

$session->bar = 'foobar';

$session->offsetSet('bar', 'foobar');
```

Getters

```
$bar = $session['bar'];

$bar = $session->bar;

$bar = $session->offsetGet('bar');
```

isset()

```
$test = isset($session['bar']);

$test = isset($session->bar);

$test = $session->offsetExists('bar');
```

unset()

```
unset($session['bar']);

unset($session->bar);

$session->offsetUnset('bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

To destroy a particular session:\

```
 $session->getManager()->getStorage()->clear('ses_variable');

  or

 unset($_SESSION['ses_variable']); 

 or

 session_destroy('ses_variable');
```